# PHP - Filter with $_GET?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, get

[image]

I'm looking to filter these small divs on the given filters on top (AB Main Hall, AB Club, Huis 23).

I'm guessing this has to be done with a $_GET? Here's my code from what I now have.

```
<?php

$concert = [
    [
        "datum" => "20 FEB",
        "naam" => "Kula Shakar",
        "zaal" => "AB Club",
        "image" => "https://img.discogs.com/Ub_IwvshvOIC1n-JL2x5mHHFfRg=/fit-in/300x300/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(40)/discogs-images/A-256590-1106988648.jpg.jpg"
    ],
    [
        "datum" => "25 FEB",
        "naam" => "Black Box",
        "zaal" => "AB Main Hall",
        "image" => "http://highly-suspect.concertticketsq.com/images/performers/event/13-concert-tickets.jpg"
    ],
    [
        "datum" => "28 FEB",
        "naam" => "Screening Pulp",
        "zaal" => "Huis 23",
        "image" => "https://dhzjvxyl79yzn.cloudfront.net/6/83626_0_layton-concert-hall.jpg"
    ],
    [
        "datum" => "4 JUN",
        "naam" => "White Box",
        "zaal" => "AB Club",
        "image" => "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9IiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIA/9k="
    ]

];

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Concerten</title>
</head>

<body>

<a href="#">AB Main Hall</a>
<a href="#">AB Club</a>
<a href="#">Huis 23</a>
    <?php foreach($concert as $concerten): ?>


    <section class="container">

        <p><?php echo $concerten['datum']; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $concerten['naam']; ?></p>
        <h2><?php echo $concerten['zaal']; ?></h2>
        <img src="<?php echo $concerten['image']; ?>"/>

    </section>

<?php endforeach; ?>  

<style>

    .container {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 50px 0px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    p {
        text-align: center;
    }



</style>
</body>

</html>
```

The items are pulled out from arrays, for example here's the first one.

```
<?php
$concert = [
    [
        "datum" => "20 FEB",
        "naam" => "Kula Shakar",
        "zaal" => "AB Club",
        "image" => "https://img.discogs.com/Ub_IwvshvOIC1n.jpg"
    ],
?>
```

Comment: If you want to make a filter, here is some pist : add some "data-xx" in your html, for example "data-zaal='AB Club' " and when you click on your filter top you use JS to hide the row who havn't data-zaal == "what you want". OR you can rebuild all the array and only show the row you want, so on click you do a foreach in php again but you only show data if $concerten['zaal'] = "what you want". Don't know if it clear enough?

Comment: I quote Mickael, I would do it with JS

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Unfortunately it needs to be done with PHP. @MickaelLeger

Comment: Maybe I will say something stupid, but if you do it only in PHP you will have to reload your page every time you click on a filter, no? If it's ok for you, try this : when you click in a filter, you add "?zaal=xxx" in your URL and when you do you foreach to display the array you add some "if (!empty $_GET['zaal']) { if ($concerten['zaal'] == $_GET['zaal'] { <- you display the row ->} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are filtering the display using `GET` variables you could achieve your goal like this.

```
<?php
    $concert = array(
        array(
            "datum" => "20 FEB",
            "naam" => "Kula Shakar",
            "zaal" => "AB Club",
            "image" => "https://img.discogs.com/Ub_IwvshvOIC1n-JL2x5mHHFfRg=/fit-in/300x300/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(40)/discogs-images/A-256590-1106988648.jpg.jpg"
        ),
        array(
            "datum" => "25 FEB",
            "naam" => "Black Box",
            "zaal" => "AB Main Hall",
            "image" => "http://highly-suspect.concertticketsq.com/images/performers/event/13-concert-tickets.jpg"
        ),
        array(
            "datum" => "28 FEB",
            "naam" => "Screening Pulp",
            "zaal" => "Huis 23",
            "image" => "https://dhzjvxyl79yzn.cloudfront.net/6/83626_0_layton-concert-hall.jpg"
        ),
        array(
            "datum" => "4 JUN",
            "naam" => "White Box",
            "zaal" => "AB Club",
            "image" => "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9IiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIAIiIA/9k="
        )
    );
    /* create array of venues from above to use in generating menu */
    $venues=array();
    foreach( $concert as $arr )$venues[]=$arr['zaal'];

    /* remove duplicates from array */
    $venues=array_unique( $venues );
    /* Add a new item to display all records */
    $venues[]='All';

    $club = isset( $_GET['zaal'] ) && in_array( $_GET['zaal'], $venues ) ?  $_GET['zaal'] : false;

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Concerten</title>
        <style>
            .container {
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin: 50px 0px;
                width: 300px;
            }
            p {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        /* display chosen club as title */
        if( $club ) printf('<h1>%s</h1>',$club);

        /* create the list of hyperlinks */
        echo '<ul>';
        array_walk( $venues, function( $club ){
            printf( '<li><a href="?zaal=%s">%s</a></li>', $club, $club );
        });
        echo '</ul>';


        foreach( $concert as $arr ){
            /* display either selected club or all clubs */
            if( $club && $club == $arr['zaal'] or $club=='All' ){
                echo "
                <section class='container'>
                    <p>{$arr['datum']}</p>
                    <p>{$arr['naam']}</p>
                    <h2>{$arr['zaal']}</h2>
                    <img src='{$arr['image']}' />
                </section>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For venues, you can use a standard function instead of `foreach`: `$venues = array_unique(array_column($concert, 'zaal'));`.

Comment: And one more thing from [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) docs: "Warning: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results.".

Comment: Pleasure - glad it helped a little.

Answer (score 0):

So first, you add some get data in your URL :

```
// Care, it may don't work I add it like this so you understand the idea
<a href="?zaal=AB_Main_Hall">AB Main Hall</a>
<a href="?zaal=AB_Club">AB Club</a>
<a href="?zaal=Huis_23">Huis 23</a>

<?php 
foreach($concert as $concerten): 
    // Check if you have some $_GET data in your url
    if (!empty($_GET['zaal']) {
        // I replace the "_" I get from the URL by " " so it will look the same as your array data
        $zaal = str_replace($_GET['zaal'], "_", " ");

        // METHOD 1 : If the row contain the good data, you display it, else do nothing
       if ($concerten['zaal'] == $zaal) {
          <section class="container">
             <p><?php echo $concerten['datum']; ?></p>
             <p><?php echo $concerten['naam']; ?></p>
             <h2><?php echo $concerten['zaal']; ?></h2>
             <img src="<?php echo $concerten['image']; ?>"/>
          </section>
       }

    // If you have no $_GET data, just display all your row
    } else {
?>

<section class="container">

    <p><?php echo $concerten['datum']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $concerten['naam']; ?></p>
    <h2><?php echo $concerten['zaal']; ?></h2>
    <img src="<?php echo $concerten['image']; ?>"/>

</section>

<?php 

} // end of else 

endforeach; 

?>
```

OTHER METOD : 
As suggested in the comment bellow :
instead of testing each row of your array then display it (cf METHOD 1) you can use `array_filter()` (doc [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php)) on your array with the filter you want then display your filtered array.

The problem with this method is that you will have to reload your page every time you want to filter. And care with how I add the $_GET data in the URL, it may be wrong but I hope you get the idea.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It is better to filter (with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), for example) data array before the loop that displays it. This way, you won't have duplicated `section` in your code.

Comment: This gave some errors I used @RamRaider suggestion before and that worked splendid. Thanks for posting though